# confirm with sb

Tags: word-usage, grammar

> I have confirmed with him that this batch of goods will be delivered tomorrow evening.

"confirm" is a transitive verb,why is it followed by an adverb "with" in the above, is it correct?

Comment: @Andrew If "confirm" is replaced by "check", does the meaning of the sentence stay the same. "check with sb that ..."

Comment: Same grammar, different meaning.  "To check" is not the same as "to confirm".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Him" is not the object of "confirmed". "That this batch of goods will be delivered ..." is the object.  "With him" is a prepositional phrase that tells us *who* helped me confirm it.

Similar examples:

> *I* (S) *related* (V) *to the police* (PP) *my tale of innocence* (DO).
>
> *I sold to him all my worldly possessions.*
>
> *I cooked for them the best meal they had ever eaten.*
>
> *I checked with her that our date for tonight was still on.*

Comment: Agreed. Nothing can normally intervene between a verb and its obj. But this is an exception where the obj is [heavy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270646/why-can-i-vary-the-position-of-the-noun-phrase-only-in-certain-sentences)

Comment: "Make a phone call to check with the supplier the delivery date."  Should I use "check" here, not "confirm"?

Comment: @user254926 It depends what you want to say.  "to check" means simply "to query".  It usually *implies* the same thing as "to confirm" (which means "to verify") but it doesn't *mean* that.